# Can I change the button "m" with space bar?

Tags: keyboard, applescript

My space bar won't work so I want to use the m button as space bar. Is there a way to do that? Maybe with the Automator using an apples riptide or something?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

I propose to use one of the option keys though: usually one of both is rarely used and you can use <kbd>M</kbd> as normal key.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Enter "Space"

   [image]
4. Enable the chosen keycode and close the window.

Answer (score 0):

I have used KeyRemap4MacBook with success before. (It has been renamed to Karabiner since)

http://lifehacker.com/5882684/the-best-keyboard-remapper-for-mac-os-x

This article gives a bit of an overview on it. The only downside is that it doesn't allow you to remap a key through the interface, you will have to do that through editing an XML file but it isn't too difficult to do.

Comment: I will give it a shot

Comment: Great, let us know how it works out for you to see if this software is worthwhile to solving a problem like this!